# Automatize multi-hop SSH and SCP with passwords

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, shell, scp

I want to access some host from my personal computer, but I have to access an intermediate server first, because the final destination cannot be seen from public internet.

The thing is that I have to do the following to access the final host. From my pc:

```
ssh username@server
```

And enter the password. Once I'm in there:

```
ssh username2@finalhost
```

And enter another password.

This is pretty cumbersome, specially when doing `scp`, because I have to copy the file to the intermediate server before being able to copy it to the final host.

**Is there  a way to make this process automatic, both for `ssh` and `scp` commands?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have [OpenSSH 7.3](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3) or later, you can use [ProxyJump](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ProxyJump) in your SSH client config to specify jump hosts.

For example, edit your `~/.ssh/config` and add

```
Host finalhost
HostName finalhost.example.com
User username2
ProxyJump username@server
```

Now `ssh finalhost` or `scp file.txt finalhost:.` should go through the jump host.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I'm pretty new to this. But where in that file are passwords stated? Shouldn't they be involved to automatize the access?

Comment: @Tendero ProxyJump doesn't store passwords, it automates the process of connecting through an intermediate ("jump") host. What so you is run something like `ssh finalhost` or `scp localsource finalhost:destination`, and it automatically connects *through* the jump host to the final host. But it'll still prompt you for both passwords. If you want to avoid the password prompts, your best option is to use [public key authentication](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication) instead of storing passwords.

Comment: @Tendero If you really must use passwords, you might be able to add something like [sshpass](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) into the mix, though I don't know offhand if that would work with two passwords. But as Gordon Davisson said, it's generally best to use pubkey auth anyway.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I don't have the opportunity to configure any of the PCs I connect to when doing `ssh`, they are both a server and a host in my University and all I have is a password to access them. Given that this is the case, is it still possible to use the publick key authentication you mention? (I don't know what that is, I shall read in a couple of hours to see what it's about.)

Comment: @Tendero Public-key auth does require installing a public key on the server (and matching private key on your client). Can you at least do this on the intermediate host, and save one password entry? The idea of storing server passwords insecurely (e.g. in a script) makes my teeth hurt, so take a look at the [sshpass](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) option jjlin mentioned.

Comment: BTW, if you're making a series of connections to the same host, another option to cut down the number of times you have to enter passwords is to use a [master connection](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/speed-multiple-ssh-connections-same-server). With that, you'd ssh into a server once, leave that connection open, then as long as it's there you can piggyback additional ssh and scp connections without needing to authenticate again.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I don't mind storing the passwords insecurely, my PC really isn't accessed by anyone but me, and the server and final host are just used to experiment with these kind of stuff. So it's not like there is some important information that could be leaked (or that there is even a possibility of someone knowing the passwords due to my storing them in a script). Is it possible to automatize the process with this in mind?

Comment: Still, whatever experiments you do, even learning, you shouldn't store passwords there. It's just bad, well, horrible practice to learn.

Comment: In case this helps anybody: I was using `scp somefile -J myjumphost targetmachine:/path`, and it seemed to be trying to resolve the final target hostname using name resolution on the client (my laptop) rather than from the bastion host like it's supposed to.  Using `ProxyJump` in the config file worked correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short block of ~/.ssh/config that will do the tric (even for old ssh versions):

```
Host server
    User username

Host finalhost
    User username2
    ProxyCommand ssh server -W %h:%p
```

You declare 2 hosts, the middle server and the final host.
The ssh connection to the server is straightforward with the **User** and **Host** provided in the config.
The connection to the finalhost performs a jump on the server as specified in the **ProxyCommand** line.

The two magic parameters **%h** and **%p** are used to forward the current Host =  finalhost and current port = 22 (default)

Secondly, in order to prevent you from typing your password each time you connect to those machines, you can use the **ssh-copy-id** command:

```
ssh-copy-id server
<type server password for the last time>

ssh-copy-id finalhost
<type finalhost password for the last time>
```

For this to work you need to have generated a public-private key pair previously using **ssh-keygen**. You can check wether or not they already exist in the ~/.ssh folder
(id_rsa.pub & id_rsa)

Comment: omg how am I just finding out about `ssh-copy-id`